# Multiple ListBox's in Drupal CCK?

Tags: drupal

I want to create content type with multiple ListBox's which populate dynamically depending on the previous.
E.x. If user selects the continent the next list box shows the list of countries present in the continent .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

Answer (score 1):

also: http://drupal.org/node/212834 (see comments also), but Hierarchical Select at current state is the best...